# Monitor application server with JMX

Tags: java, jmx, jmx-ws

I found this simple example of JBoss monitoring with JMX and Java

```
public class JMXExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Get a connection to the JBoss AS MBean server on localhost
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 9999;  // management-native port
        String urlString =
            System.getProperty("jmx.service.url","service:jmx:remoting-jmx://" + host + ":" + port);
        JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
        JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, null);
        MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();

        //Invoke on the JBoss AS MBean server
        int count = connection.getMBeanCount();
        System.out.println(count);
        jmxConnector.close();
    }
}
```

I want to call this code every 3 seconds to get live performance data.

Is there a way to open one connection to the server and send frequent requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy this code as an EJB, you can make it a `@Singleton @Startup`, with the connection being set at a `@PostConstruct` method, while the metrics are gathered periodically, according to a `@Schedule`. For instance:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MetricsGathering {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // setup the connection
    }

    @Schedule(second="*/5")
    public void collect() {
        // get the data and do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the code in Java standalone application. Can you show me some code example how I can make one connection and reuse it many times?

Comment: If your standalone application is running 24x7, you can either make the connection part of a static field, or use a Singleton pattern. If your standalone application starts, run this code, and shuts down, there's no possibility to keep the connection.